# Defining new variable from Subquery - Only scalar expressions are allowed. (SQL Server)

Tags: sql, subquery, calculated-columns, alter-table, sql-view

I'm trying to add a column [Missed 2x] to an existing table that indicates whether the Subject has had two consecutive missed diaries. The value is "Missed 2x" if the most recent 2 diaries are missed, and NULL otherwise. I wrote a select statement (within the code below) that successfully pulls the IDs who meet this criteria. When I created a User-Defined Function to cross-check the table and assign the value, it was untenable, as the function is recalculated for every ID every time that table is queried and took forever.

I attempted to assign the value via Alter Table by seeing if the ID of the existing table is in the Subset table. I figured this should save resources since the subset table is defined once, and the Alter statement simply checks if each ID is in the subset. Then I became aware that I can't do this with Alter Table as I get the error *Subqueries are not allowed in this context. Only scalar expressions are allowed.*

What is the most efficient alternative?

```
ALTER TABLE [R3008_Subjchar] add [Missed 2x] as 
    case when [Subject ID] in 
        (
        select
        [Subject ID]
        from(
                select distinct 
                [Subject ID]
                , [Questionnaire Name]
                , [Task Date]
                , [Is Completed]
                , dense_rank () over (Partition by [Subject ID], [Questionnaire Name] order by [Task Date] desc) as recency
                from dbo.R3008_Questionnaire
                ) r
        where recency <=2
        group by [Subject ID]
        having count(case when [Is Completed] = 'no' and [Questionnaire Name] = 'FLU-PRO Questionnaire' then [Is Completed] end) = 2
        )
    then 'Missed 2x' end
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a subquery in a computed column; it may only access the data that is on the current row, not other rows.

I don't think that storing such information is a good idea. Instead, you can create a view; `lag()` comes handy to implement the logic you want:

```
create view v_r3008_questionnaire
select q.*,
    case when [Is Completed] = 'no'
              and lag([Is Completed]) over(partition by [Subject ID], [Questionnaire Name] order by [Task Date]) = 'no'
        then 'Missed 2x'
    end as [Missed 2x]
from dbo.r3008_questionnaire
```

For each "failed" row, this check if the previous status for the same subject and questionnaire is failed as well, and sets the flag in that case.